# Training data for classification with dimensionality reduction. How do we test the model prediction?

Tags: classification, pca

Hi I'm sorry if my question is a bit basic. But I need help with understanding classification with dimensionality reduction. Say I have a training matrix, X containing n $\times$ m. And m is a very large number. I apply PCA and truncate X to some k and I call this truncated, X as X$_{reduced}$ which reduces the number of feature, m. I train the classification with X$_{reduced}$.

Say I have a new dataset, do I need to perform PCA again on the new dataset? I'm a bit confused because when applying PCA on the new dataset, the variance will not be equal to that in the training data set. But the number of features (columns) have to be equal, right? Does it matter if the variance is not the same?

Thank you in advance. Sorry again if my question is a bit noob.